# Batch loop problems not resulting in reading first line of doc

Tags: batch

I have the following script:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
pause

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ("%cd%\src\check.txt") do (
    set error[!count!]=%%i
    set /a count+=1
)

echo "%error[0]%"
pause
```

This gives me the path of the check.txt file but it should give me the first line of this doc. If I take away the "" in the path then it works.

The problem is then the code fails if i have spaces in the folder path which is really anoying to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use relative path instead?

As such:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
pause

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (.\src\check.txt) do (
    set error[!count!]=%%i
    set /a count+=1
)

echo "%error[0]%"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output of `find /counter` to define your line according to its own line number in the file:

```powershell
@echo off & setlocal

for /f usebacktokens^=1*delims^=^[^] %%i in (`
   find /n /v "" ^<"%cd%\src\check.txt"`)do set "_error%%~i=%%~j"

echo; %_error1%
endlocal
```

---

- **Obs.:**

> ```powershell
> :: setlocal enabledelayedexpansion // it is not necessary
> :: set count=0                     // it is not necessary
> ```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [How do `SETLOCAL` and `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18464353/8177207)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Answer (score 0):

If i recall correctly, you should use

```
set /a count=0
```

If i understand correctly, why dont you change to the correct directory before you go into the loop, eg.

```
pushd "c:\path\to\file"

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (check.txt) do (
    set error[!count!]=%%i
    set /a count+=1
)

popd REM return from the directory

echo %error[0]%
echo %error[1]%
```